# Implement a 32x64 register file in Verilog

Tags: verilog, armv8

Here are the specifications of the register file:

- Buses A, B, and W are 64 bits wide.

  When RegWr is set to 1, then the data on Bus W is stored in the
  register     specified by Rw, on the negative (falling) clock edge.

  Register 31 must always read zero.

  Data from registers (as specified by Ra and Rb) is sent on Bus A and
  Bus B respectively, after a delay of 2 tics.

  Writes to the register file must have a delay of 3 tics.

The Register File module should have the following interface:

```
module RegisterFile(BusA, BusB, BusW, RA, RB, RW, RegWr, Clk);
```

Here is my current program

```
module RegisterFile(BusA, BusB, BusW, RA, RB, RW, RegWr, Clk);
 output [63:0] BusA;
 output [63:0] BusB;
 output [63:0] BusW;
 input RA;
 input RB;
 input RW;
 input RegWr;
 input Clk;
 reg [31:0] registers [31:0];

 assign #2 BusA = registers [0];
 assign #2 BusB = registers [1];

 always @ (negedge Clk) begin
  if(RegWr & RW !=0)
    registers[RW] <= #3 BusW;
 end
endmodule
```

I am wondering how to initialize the RA and RB to zero, and wondering how to send the data from RA and RB to BusA and BusB correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things that need to be changed in the code first

1. BusA, BusB and BusW are data buses each 64 bits wide. BusW is being used as the input bus, while BusA and BusB are output buses. Therefore the declaration of the ports needs to change as

   ```
   input [63:0] BusW;
   output [63:0] BusA, BusB;
   ```
2. The register file has a depth of 32. and RA, RB and RW are the address buses. These addresses need to be 5 bits wide.

   ```
   input [4:0] RA,RB,RW;
   ```
3. The complete code can then be re-written as

   ```
   module RegisterFile(BusA, BusB, BusW, RA, RB, RW, RegWr, Clk);
     output [63:0] BusA, BusB;
     input [63:0] BusW;
     input [4:0] RA, RB, RW;
     input RegWr;
     input Clk;

     reg [63:0] registers [31:0];

     assign #2 BusA = registers[RA];
     assign #2 BusB = registers[RB];

     always @ (negedge Clk) 
     begin
       if(RegWr)
         if (RW != 4'd31)
           registers[RW] <= #3 BusW;
         else 
           // This is done to allow the user to reset the 0th location to a zero value.
           registers[0] <= #3 'd0; 
     end
   endmodule
   ```

I have simulated this code on edaplayground and also created a small testbench to test it. Here is the link to the code and testbench
https://www.edaplayground.com/x/5DXC